# how to make json object with for loop from input textbox name and it's value

Tags: javascript, json

I have three different input text boxes with the name 21, 22, 23 I want to make a json object with name as key and value as value.

```
{ "21": "somevalue", "22": "somevalue", "23": "somevalue" }

 var getInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 var getNames = getInputs[0].getAttribute("name");
       var count = getInputs.length;
       var obj = {};
                for(var x=0; x<count.length; x++){                    
                obj[x] = getNames;
            }
```

Comment: `count` is already the length, so the second you call `.length` you're trying to get the length of the length, and that's an error? Also, you're writing the same name to `obj` on each iteration

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) is a language independent representation of a data structure. What you are looking for is a plain old object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it...

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var obj = {};
for(var x=0; x < inputs.length; x++){   
    var input = inputs[x];
    obj[input.name] = input.value;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<input name="nameone" value="valueone">
<input name="nametwo" value="valuetwo">
```

Comment: when i console.log(obj) it doesn't show anything except Obj{}

Comment: did you try it with the snippet? I had a typo in my original post

Comment: O not yet wait please

Comment: Yes it is making fine json, but my console dosen't show it for long time, it's  shows just for a milisecond and disappear

Comment: Glad this answered your question. It sounds like you've got something else going on - it should stay in the console (like it does in the snippet here on SO).

Comment: it stays when i run code snippet button on this site, but when i copy it in my file and run the function as onclick button then it shows for a while and goes off